# music loading/playing glitch

Tags: java, android

I have a quick and dirty solution that might not work on android versions 2 and up.

The problem involved music preference (true or false) and loading the music. Basically, if the music preference was off, and then the user turns it on, the music loads in another thread but the function also calls play_music() right away. But the music doesn't play since it takes a relatively long while to load the music and the play_music() function called and ended. However, if then user turns off the music then turns it back on right away, the music plays since it's already loaded.

To get around this, I continually called this piece of code in the update method:

```
if (scr_get_pref_music() == true && Assets.msc_song != null)
{
    Assets.msc_song.play();
}
```

It works on my android phone (version 4.04), but I wanna know if continually calling the play() function will cause any glitches or stuttering music in other versions of android (2 and up).

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might help you,

```
int status = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ADB_ENABLED, 0);
```

If it is enabled, status== 1, otherwise status== 0.

Atleast it works for me.